# Awk--For loop by comparing two files

Tags: for-loop, awk

I have two big files.

File 1 looks like following:

```
10 2864001 2864012
10 5942987 5943316
```

File 2 looks like following:

```
10 2864000 28
10 2864001 28
10 2864002 28
10 2864003 27
10 2864004 28
10 2864005 26
10 2864006 26
10 2864007 26
10 2864008 26
10 2864009 26
10 2864010 26
10 2864011 26
10 2864012 26
```

So I want to create a for loop in such a way that,

1. First column of File 1 **must** match first column of File 2 AND
2. To start a for loop by matching second column of File 1 with second
   column of File 2  AND
3. Sum third column of File 2 until third column of File 1 match to
   second column of File 2.

So the output of above example should be sum of third column of File 2 for first line of File 1 which is 347. I tried to use NR and FNR but I have not been able to do it so far. Could you please help me to generate awk script?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Transcribed, so there may be typos:

```
awk '
BEGIN { lastFNR=0; acount=0; FIRST="T"}

FNR < lastFNR {FIRST="F"; aindex=0; next}

FIRST=="T" {
      sta[acount] = $2
      fna[acount] = $3
      acount += 1
      lastFNR=FNR         
}

FIRST=="F" && $2 >= sta[index] && $2 <= fna[aindex] {
      sum[aindex] += $3
      lastFNR = FNR
}

FIRST=="F" && $2 > fna[aindex] {
      aindex ==1
      if (aindex > acount) { FIRST="E" }
}

END {
      for(aindex=0; aindex<acount; +=aindex) {
            print sta[aindex], "through", fna[index], "totals", sum[aindex]
      }
}
' file 1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
awk -f s.awk file1 file2
```

where `s.awk` is

```
NR==FNR {
    a[$1,$2]=$3
    next
}
($1,$2) in a {
    do {
        s+=$3
        if ((getline)+0 < 1) break
    } while ($2 != a[$1,$2])
    print s
}
{ s=0 }
```

output:

```
319
```